# test if compressed archives contain same data

Tags: r, compression

Is it possible to test if the contents of compressed archives are the same without needing to decompress them?  What is the standard way of doing this in R?  I was thinking of hashing them, like and md5 or something, but this all takes more time and is it necessary?  I don't care about times the archives were created or anything like that, only if the contents of the files are the same.

Example (creates some test files on your comp.)

```
## Create some test files
dir.create("test1")
dir.create('test2')
writeLines(text="hi", con="test1/test1.txt")
writeLines(text="hi*2", con="test2/test2.txt")

## Make some compressed archives
tar("test.tar.gzip2", files="test1", compression="bzip2")  # should be same as test1.tar.gzip2
tar("test1.tar.gzip2", files="test1", compression="bzip2")
tar("test2.tar.gzip2", files="test2", compression="bzip2")
```

I want to be able to test that "test.tar.gzip2" and "test1.tar.gzip2" are the same, but "test2.tar.gzip2" is different.  How?

Comment: You could calculate the MD5 checksum, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following function extract the bytes from a file which you can then compare:

```
 binRead <- function(fName){
  f_s <- file.info(fName)$size
  f <- file(fName,"rb")
  res <- readBin(f,"raw",f_s)
  close(f)
  return(res)
}

t0 <- binRead("test.tar.gzip2")
t1 <- binRead("test1.tar.gzip2")
t2 <- binRead("test2.tar.gzip2")
all(t0 == t1) #true
all(t0 == t2) #false
```